# Initializing TableView with columns inside fx:root using FXML

Tags: java, javafx

I have a custom class inside a fxml file called `TablePatientView`. I use it like `<TablePatientView fx:id="tablePatientView" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="45.0" prefHeight="409.0" prefWidth="363.0" />` and it works almost fine. The `fx:root` looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.TableView" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <TableView>
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="patId" prefWidth="101.0" text="Patient-ID" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="patVorname" prefWidth="69.0" text="Vorname" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="patNachname" prefWidth="98.0" text="Nachname" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="patGebdat" prefWidth="96.0" text="Geburtsdatum" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</fx:root>
```

with the following class

```
public class TablePatientView extends TableView<TablePatient> {

    private Parent root;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient,String> patId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient,String> patVorname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient,String> patNachname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient, LocalDate> patGebdat;

    public TablePatientView() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/fxml/TablePatientView.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);
        try {
            root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setCellValueFactories();
        // getColumns().addAll(patId, patVorname, patNachname, patGebdat); works, but not with plain fxml
    }

    private void setCellValueFactories() {
        patId.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().idProperty().asString());
        patVorname.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().vornameProperty());
        patNachname.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().nachnameProperty());
        patGebdat.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().gebDatProperty());
    }
}
```

The columns are correctly initialized, but for some reason not added as columns to the TableView.
I know I can do it via java code (see the commented line in the code above) but I would like to know why this doesn't work with just fxml. Using the <TableView> directly inside fxml without a custom class and root works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<fx:root type="TableView">` references a `TableView` which is supplied via the call to `loader.setRoot(this)`.

You have defined another `TableView` inside that `TableView`<sup>1</sup>. The columns are added to that `TableView`, not the one referenced by `<fx:root>`.

The correct FXML is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.TableView" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="patId" prefWidth="101.0" text="Patient-ID" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="patVorname" prefWidth="69.0" text="Vorname" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="patNachname" prefWidth="98.0" text="Nachname" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="patGebdat" prefWidth="96.0" text="Geburtsdatum" />
    </columns>
</fx:root>
```

---

### Alternative approach

I'm not a big fan of subclassing control classes, such as `TableView`. The reason is that you're not really adding functionality to the `TableView`, you're just essentially setting properties on it, and this is not a good use of inheritance.

Consider instead using a creational pattern. A simple static factory method works well, and plays nicely with FXML via the `fx:factory` attribute.

TablePatientView.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<TableView xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.jamesd.examples.TablePatientController">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="patId" prefWidth="101.0" text="Patient-ID" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="patVorname" prefWidth="69.0" text="Vorname" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="patNachname" prefWidth="98.0" text="Nachname" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="patGebdat" prefWidth="96.0" text="Geburtsdatum" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

TablePatientController.java:

```
public class TablePatientController {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient,String> patId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient,String> patVorname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient,String> patNachname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablePatient, LocalDate> patGebdat;
    
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        setCellValueFactories();
    }

    private void setCellValueFactories() {
        patId.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().idProperty().asString());
        patVorname.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().vornameProperty());
        patNachname.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().nachnameProperty());
        patGebdat.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().gebDatProperty());
    }
}
```

Tables.java:

```
public class Tables {

    public static TableView<TablePatient> tablePatientView() throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/fxml/TablePatientView.fxml"));
        return loader.load();
    }
}
```

And then you can use this in FXML with

```xml
<Tables fx:factory="tablePatientView" />
```

---

### Footnote

1. What happens here is that the second `TableView` is added to the original `TableView`'s `items` list, since the `@DefaultProperty` of a `TableView` is that list. So eventually the table view would attempt to display that as a row in the table. It seems like there should be a `ClassCastException` at some point, but possibly it gets silently squashed since FXML can't specify generic types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my issue. First off you were right, I did get a `ClassCastException` later on. I extended `TableView` because I wanted to declutter my other controller which contains 3 separate `TableViews` and some buttons in total. I will give the static factory a try, thanks again :)

Comment: @wand555 You can also consider using `fx:include`.